# Como inserir nova linha no arquivo json, usando PHP?

Tags: php, json

No trecho do código `config.json`, preciso que, sempre que rodar um script PHP, ele insira uma nova linha abaixo, com o número em sequência e id correspondente:

```
"assignment": {
                "0": "292",
                "1": "280",
                "2": "233",
                "3": "308"
            }
```

Como faço para ele encontrar esses números (1,2,3,etc) para inserir o próximo em sequencia e colocar a variável $id na segunda coluna?

Ex: o próximo $id = 999. Aí iria inserir:

```
"assignment": {
                "0": "292",
                "1": "280",
                "2": "233",
                "3": "308"
                "4": "999"
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode fazer desta maneira

```
// extrai a informação do ficheiro
$string = file_get_contents("config.json");
// faz o decode o json para uma variavel php que fica em array
$json = json_decode($string, true);

// aqui é onde adiciona a nova linha ao ao array assignment
$json["assignment"][] = "999";

// abre o ficheiro em modo de escrita
$fp = fopen('config.json', 'w');
// escreve no ficheiro em json
fwrite($fp, json_encode($json));
// fecha o ficheiro
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, transforme e `array`:

```
/*Vendo que, a variável é o nome do array, previamente implementado*/

$assignment = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Na sequência, usando OU `array_push` ou mesmo incrementando o array manualmente:

***1ª opção:***

```
array_push($assignment,$novo_valor);
```

***2ª opção:***

```
$assignment[] = $novo_valor;
```

Vendo que teu índice é em número, não é necessário indicar um valor no índice.
Para resolver tua questão, devolva o valor JSON ao array:

```
$json = json_encode($assignment);
```

Comment: eu sou novo com isso, onde que eu chamo o arquivo config.json? o $novo_valor seria por exemplo: $novo_valor = '999'?

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo na Resposta do Ricardo Rosa ele mostra o `file_get_contents`, para ter o conteúdo do arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Contando o número de arrays dentro de `'assigniment'`, como a função `count()` inicia em 1, então ele sempre terá um valor maior que o último id, no seu caso:

```
$id=count($json['assignment']);
```

> [Referência da função count()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php)

Para inserir uma nova linha, pode usar:

```
$json['assignment'][]=$novo_valor_a_ser_adicionado;
```